# ActiveMQ converting existing Queue to CompositeQueue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I'll try to explain this the best I can.

As I store my data that I receive from my ActiveMQ queue in several distinct locations, I have decided to build a composite Queue so I can process the data for each location individually.

The issue I am running into is that I currently have the Queue in a production environment. It seems that changing a queue named A to a composite Queue also called A having virtual destinations named B and C causes me to lose all the data on the existing Queue. It does not on start-up forward the previous messages. Currently, I am creating a new CompositeQueue with a different name, say D, which forwards data to B and C. Then I have some clunky code that prevents all connections until I have both a) updated all the producers to send to D and b) pulled the data from A using a consumer and sent it to D with a producer.

It feels rather messy. Is there any way around this? Ideally I would be able to keep the same Queue name, have all its current data sent to the composite sub-queues, and have the Queue forward only in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description given the desired behavior is no possible as message routing on the composite queue works when messages are in-flight and not sometime later when that queue has already stored messages and the broker configuration is changed.  You need to consume the past messages from the initial Queue (A I guess it is) and send them onto the destinations desired.

Comment: I was afraid of that; it makes writing backwards compatible code (in my case) difficult. Thanks for confirming that my solution is the right way forward.